# Turn a Visual Studio Project/Solution on GitHub into a CMake project?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I have some Visual Studio projects on GitHub, and I recently found that I need to work with these projects on MacOS. But since these projects are mostly written in C++, and Visual Studio for Mac doesn't support C++ project for now, so I decided to turn these C++ project into CMake projects, since Visual Studio support building CMake project. Instead of creating a new repository on GitHub, is it possible to turn my current project(or solution, `.sln`, in VS terminology) into a CMake project, so I can keep those git commits I have made?

Comment: Are you asking for a vs project to CMake converter?

Comment: @jpr33: If you can explain how you do it, that would be better than simply provide me a converter.

Comment: I mean CMake projects are made up of cmake code. I think you are asking for a cmake tutorial: https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remarks:

- You can switch the build system (CMake, Visual Studio project) without changing the repository and usually you can also keep the overall structure.
- Build systems are just text files filled with instructions interpreted by the build system.
- You can keep both build systems for the times being and one you are happy with your new one, you can delete the old one.
- Technically a Visual Studio project can also be a CMake project, but I won't nitpick here.
- You should learn some CMake with a toy project before you start converting your existing projects.

How to get a CMake project:

1. Add a CMakeLists.txt file in the top level directory. It should at least contain the `project` command defining the project name and used languages.
2. Create a build directory, call `cmake <path-to-your-project>` and some trivial project is created.
3. Add sub-directories, targets, and find commands for external dependencies.
4. Beside running CMake, you can also compile your project now and check that the parts you added are working fine. This can be done using Windows and OS X.
5. Add commits with your changes and push them to your repository (maybe as a branch).
6. Repeat 3. to 5. until finished.